# This [edit] fails an audit review

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

The [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edit) tag has just over [2300 questions asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edit) over the past nine years, and the tag is so ambiguous that it is used for everything from editing MS Office Documents to editing audio files:

> to modify (a computer file) by, for example, deleting, inserting,
>   moving, or copying text.

Should edit be burninated?  Well, I had to scan through 161 results to see that it doesn't look like this has been discussed before.  There's not even a good way to search for that as the word "edit" is used so frequently both here on SOmeta but also on the main SO site.

Here's the logic according to the [burninate guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Although it describes the contents of the questions, it is far from unambiguous.  Editing is a VERY broad topic.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Sure, it's on topic for every technology-oriented Stack Exchange site.  If people actually used the tag properly we'd have millions of posts tagged with "edit" on each site as it's so broad.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

I don't think it adds anything meaningful to the post.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

I think this one is the key, it means so many different things in each context.  It could be used to describe reading then saving a file using a file system, detecting the ability to change a cell value in a grid/table control, parsing an audio file to remove noise or clicks, changing the value of a JSON object, and many more.

Comment: Suggested title: This [ edit ] fails an audit review

Comment: Sure, I'm game :)

Comment: Let's [ edit ] this tag out

Comment: "it's on topic for every technology-oriented Stack Exchange site", no it's for every "content-oriented" site.

Comment: Oh yeah, this one need to go.

Comment: We probably should edit \[edit\] out.

Comment: I think this one is actually a no-brainer. The ambiguity alone seems to indicate a need to burninate

Comment: I'm disappointed this isn't tagged `edit`, as it is about editing tags.

Comment: Was there an answer here that got deleted? I can't find my comment, but I think I was suggesting to also consider burning similar concepts [tag:move] and [tag:revision] for the same arguments as [tag:edit].

Comment: There was an answer here that was deleted, yes.